# Sqlite database copies data from other database's column

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I got a sqlite database like this:

```
_id | word | spell | detail | created | is_deleted | phonetic
______________________________________________________________
 1  | hello| hello | ok     |173569854|      0     | /hello/
______________________________________________________________

 2  | nice | nice  | test   |156489874|      0     | /nice/
______________________________________________________________
.
.
.
```

and now I want to create a new database which is like this:

```
_id | word | phonetic
_____________________
```

how can I copy data from the original database to the new database?

Answer (score 1):

You mean a new table?

You can do the following:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable
SELECT _id, word, phonetic 
FROM OldTable
```

Comment: But what should I do if two tables are not in the same database?

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471003/copying-table-in-one-db-to-another-db-in-ios-by-sqlite3