# Create a new SQLite database from an old one

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I have a big SQLite database with a lot of tables I don't need (about 200 tables) and 10 tables I want to keep. I want to trim the database as much as I can, because it's going to go into an Android app. So, basically, I want to copy 10 tables from a SQLite database to another database, and discard the rest.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In about 10 seconds of using google I found the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471003/copying-table-in-one-db-to-another-db-in-ios-by-sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

Why not to copy the original file using filecopy features.
After that you can [DROP](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html) not needed tables?
Finally you can [COMPACT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) db.

If you do not need anymore the 190 tables you could avoid the file copy.
;-)

dex